# Search with text not in order, in an SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a column storing a string that is a concatenation of different days, say "Monday, Wednesday, Saturday, Sunday", is there a command in SQL, which would return that string, by only searching for "Wednesday, Sunday"?

Something along the lines of the command below:

```
    SELECT * FROM `information` WHERE Days = "Wednesday, Sunday"
```

Comment: Seriously consider normalising your schema, or otherwise amending your storage model

Comment: sounds like a regular expression REGEX to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of days is a string

```
SELECT * FROM `information` WHERE Days LIKE '%Wednesday%' AND Days LIKE '%Sunday%'
```

**EDIT**
Changed `OR` to `AND` to get rows having both dates

Comment: I found that this works by replacing OR with AND, and by adding '%' to either side of each day-string, just to eliminate the possibility of placing it in the wrong order. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Regular expressions.It supported in all commonly used DB engines.

In MySql there is `RLIKE` Operator, so your query would be something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM `information` WHERE Days RLIKE '(Wednesday|Sunday)+.*(Wednesday|Sunday)+';
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your source query into a like query, assuming the search string is in the right order:

```
SELECT *
FROM information
WHERE Days LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(REPLACE('Wednesday, Saturday', ', ', '%'), ',', '%')), '%')
```

The expression converts

```
Wednesday, Saturday
```

to

```
%Wednesday%Saturday%
```

Comment: This does not return a result that is "Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday" and the question did specify order should not matter to the query.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the LIKE command

```
SELECT * FROM `information` WHERE Days LIKE "%Wednesday% AND Days LIKE '%Sunday%";
```

Comment: That won't perform the match requested in the OP.